# Phrase similar to Key User

Tags: phrase-requests

I'm developing a new business tool regarding digitization/digitalization of key processes. The idea is that each department in the company selects one person who builds/finds/utilizes some technology to advance the company, and I need something to call them. We already use "Key User" for a different role so I need something that has a similar meaning but very different sound to differentiate between the two.

It can refer to digitalization, paperless, technology advancement ect.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it looks like a request for help naming "a new thing" - so it's just as Off Topic as asking for suggestions when naming programming variables and such.

Comment: I didn't really want anything original/new, and selected an answer that posted already created names that are used in many different scenarios. Sorry if that wasn't clear.

Comment: It's quite clear to me what you're asking. It's also quite obvious to me that although your company has already co-opted "Key User" for some highly specific context, this in no way justifies the assumption that this is somehow an "established usage" (such as might be used in exactly the same way in *other* organisations, or be unambiguously defined that way in a dictionary). It really is just a "naming suggestion" question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you're looking for a catchy title, there are many possible answers. Here are a few:

- Tech. Captains
- Tech. Masters
- Tech. Advancers
- Tech. Leaders
- Tech. Vanguard Members
- Superusers
- Sudos (from UNIX)

Comment: Thanks! Super user sounds perfect. I appreciate the help

Answer (score -1):

How about a [maven](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/maven)?

[maven](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/maven)

[The term was popularised by Malcolm Gladwell in his book The Tipping Point](https://digest.bps.org.uk/2015/05/22/you-can-now-test-whether-someone-is-a-maven/)

[The Tipping Point - Four Minute Read](https://fourminutebooks.com/the-tipping-point-summary/)

[mavens are specialists who possess the power of recommendation.](https://www.telegraph.co.uk/culture/4720659/Are-you-a-maven-or-a-connector.html)

The paragraph below was taken from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Tipping_Point#The_three_rules)'s page on the Tipping Point but cites directly from the book.

> Mavens are "information specialists", or "people we rely upon to connect us with new information".[5](https://www.telegraph.co.uk/culture/4720659/Are-you-a-maven-or-a-connector.html) They accumulate knowledge, especially about the marketplace, and know how to share it with others. Gladwell cites Mark Alpert as a prototypical Maven who is "almost pathologically helpful", further adding, "he can't help himself".[8] In this vein, Alpert himself concedes, "A Maven is someone who wants to solve other people's problems, generally by solving his own".[8] According to Gladwell, Mavens start "word-of-mouth epidemics" due to their knowledge, social skills, and ability to communicate.[9] As Gladwell states: "Mavens are really information brokers, sharing and trading what they know".[10]
>
> The word maven comes from the Yiddish meyvn, meaning "one who understands." But to be a maven you have to more than just understand a topic, you have to know its ins and outs. Often mavens are the people that you turn to as experts in a field. You don't become a maven overnight. That kind of expertise comes with an accumulation of knowledge over the years.
>
> someone who is dazzlingly skilled in any field
>
> Whether it's in fashion, or food, or forensic science, someone who really knows his stuff about a topic is a maven, or a person particularly skilled in the field.

You could probably call them a tech-maven

Answer (score -1):

**Key** as an *adjective* means "of crucial importance".

Example: *she became a key figure in the suffragette movement*

Synonyms:

> basic, central, chief, critical, crucial, decisive, dominant, essential, fundamental, important, indispensable, leading, main, major, pivotal, prime, principal, salient, significant, vital.

For **Key User**, in the context you mention, I would pick one of the above or consider also:

- Super User
- Builder User
- [Department/Build/Innovation/Digitalization] Representative